# Change some rules for Python code formating in IntelliJ when inside a try statement

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I am trying to push some code to a repository with a Git hook that check Python code formating.

However, when I use IntelliJ automatic formating function, it changes the following code:

```
from package1 import SomeClass


class Foo:
    # ...


try:
    from package2 import OtherClass

    class Bar:
        # ...
```

to this (two blank lines instead of one after the `try`):

```
from package1 import SomeClass


class Foo:
    # ...


try:
    from package2 import OtherClass


    class Bar:
        # ...
```

The second example is refused by the hook.

I would like to have automatic formating set to keep only one blank line like in the first example. I tried playing a bit with the settings in `Editor>Code Style>Python`, but there is alway one additional blank line somewhere.

I am using **IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.3**.

Answer (score 0):

According to [pep8's blank lines spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines), `Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.` and that's why this is happening, as the class `Bar` is not an inner class.
You can change it in `Editor>Code Style>Python>Blank Lines` and set `1` to `Around top-level classes and functions`. 
**Note** that this will cause IntelliJ to format **all** top-level classes and functions to have only 1 blank line between them. So you can only format to the style you showed, or:

```
from package1 import SomeClass

class Foo:
    # ...

try:
    from package2 import OtherClass

    class Bar:
    # ...
```